# 500 Error Django file upload

Tags: python, django, apache, django-models, django-views

I have been using [this code](https://github.com/Alem/django-jfu) to produce a file uploader and I can only get as far as getting the template to attempt an upload. I am wondering if I need to either configure Apache, add something to Django settings or install some more libraries maybe?

I have followed all the steps mentioned on that page, but please ask if you suspect I may have carried one or two of them out incorrectly.

**Error**

```
jssor.slider.js

Error INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

**Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_file_form',
    'django_file_form.ajaxuploader',
    'jfu',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/Jonathan/Documents/django/bible/bible/static/jfu'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from jfu.http import upload_receive, UploadResponse, JFUResponse

@require_POST
def upload( request ):

    # The assumption here is that jQuery File Upload
    # has been configured to send files one at a time.
    # If multiple files can be uploaded simulatenously,
    # 'file' may be a list of files.
    file = upload_receive( request )

    instance = YOURMODEL( file = file )
    instance.save()

    basename = os.path.basename( instance.file.path )

    file_dict = {
        'name' : basename,
        'size' : file.size,

        'url': settings.MEDIA_URL + basename,
        'thumbnailUrl': settings.MEDIA_URL + basename,

        'deleteUrl': reverse('jfu_delete', kwargs = { 'pk': instance.pk }),
        'deleteType': 'POST',
    }

    return UploadResponse( request, file_dict )

@require_POST
def upload_delete( request, pk ):
    success = True
    try:
        instance = YOURMODEL.objects.get( pk = pk )
        os.unlink( instance.file.path )
        instance.delete()
    except YOURMODEL.DoesNotExist:
        success = False

    return JFUResponse( request, success )
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from bible import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'bible.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^verses/', views.index),
    url(r'^search/', views.search),
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact),
    url(r'^profile/', views.profile),
    url(r'^register', views.register),

    url( r'upload/', views.upload, name = 'jfu_upload' ),

    # You may optionally define a delete url as well
    url( r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.upload_delete, name = 'jfu_delete' ),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

class Photo( models.Model ):
    file = models.FileField( upload_to = settings.MEDIA_ROOT )
```

Comment: Can you get the stacktrace from the error?

Comment: I can't see anything else on the page, it could even be a JavaScript error. There isn't a django debug section at the bottom of the screen if that's what you mean?

Comment: Why mediaroot is not set ?

Comment: I don't know, I guess I didn't see a need for it. Is it necessary?

Comment: I think it is something to do with the server Django is running on, as the demo also throws an error. Anyone know how to configure Django to accept file uploads?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the database. I think it was corrupted somehow and wouldn't talk with the application properly. Rebuilding it and running `python manage.py migrate` seemed to do the trick.